# Deserialization of structure data sent by Big Endian system in Little Endian system

Tags: c, sockets, endianness

I have a C program that receives data from a mainframe in a UDP packet over sockets.  The host of the C program is changing from Unix (big endian) to Linux (little endian) and the program no longer works.  I do not currently have the option of changing the mainframe client program.

The program performs a `recvfrom` and receives data into a char array.  Previously we were able to simply cast this buffer to a structure matching what was passed from MF and everything worked perfect.  Now, due to the different byte alignments the mapping to the structure fails.  Here is the structure and some code.

```
struct CCClntPkt
{
    unsigned short packet_type;
    unsigned short reply_socket;
    unsigned long  msg_ID;
    unsigned short msg_length;
    unsigned char  client_string[250];
};
```

The code previously used to cast the received data buffer to this structure looks something like:

```
char BCpacket_in[MAX_PACKET];
struct CCClntPkt *pClntPkt;

<snip>

rcv_cnt = recvfrom(BCServerSocket, BCpacket_in,
                sizeof(BCpacket_in),0x0,(struct sockaddr *)&from,
                &fromlen);

if (rcv_cnt > 0)
{
    pClntPkt = (struct CCClntPkt *) &BCpacket_in;
}
```

I was able to get the correct values for packet_type and reply_socket by using `ntohs` but the character field client_string is mangled.  I also tried putting a `pragma pack(1)` before and `pragma pack(0)` after the structure but there still seems to be an alignment problem.

I also tried bit shifting values from `BCpacket_in` and was able to get the correct values for packet_type and reply_socket but cannot figure out how to pull out the ulong msg_ID.  Code for that was:

```
packet_type = BCpacket_in[0] << 8;
packet_type |= BCpacket_in[1];

reply_to_socket = BCpacket_in[2] << 8;
reply_to_socket |= BCpacket_in[3];

/*
msg_ID = BCpacket_in[4] << 24;
msg_ID |= BCpacket_in[5] << 16;
msg_ID |= BCpacket_in[6] << 8;
msg_ID |= BCpacket_in[7];
*/
```

I am pretty stumped at this point so any help is appreciated.  I am not the original author of this program and my C knowledge is pretty limited.  I don't mind doing the work though so I would appreciate being provided any relevant references as well.  Thanks!

Comment: The code you have commented out should do the trick, assuming it is a 32-bit machine. char << int gives the resulting type int, after integer promotions. On a 16 bit machine, int may be 16 bit and the code won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to parse the received packet (`BCpacket_in`) into a `struct CCClntPkt` packet manually, that's the only portable way of doing this. Endianness translations are properly handled with the `ntohl` (network-to-host `long`) family of functions; see the manpages `byteorder(3)` and `endian(3)`.

These functions assume that all packets are sent over the wire as big-endian, because that's the internet standard.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the sizes of the various types differ from your big endian host to your new little endian host.

If you compile this program on your both of your hosts, it will show you the sizes and layout of the `struct`:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct CCClntPkt
{
    unsigned short packet_type;
    unsigned short reply_socket;
    unsigned long  msg_ID;
    unsigned short msg_length;
    unsigned char  client_string[250];
};

int main()
{
    printf("sizeof(unsigned short) = %u\n", (unsigned)sizeof(unsigned short));
    printf("sizeof(unsigned long) = %u\n", (unsigned)sizeof(unsigned long));

    printf("offsetof(struct CCClntPkt, reply_socket) = %u\n", (unsigned)offsetof(struct CCClntPkt, reply_socket));
    printf("offsetof(struct CCClntPkt, msg_ID) = %u\n", (unsigned)offsetof(struct CCClntPkt, msg_ID));
    printf("offsetof(struct CCClntPkt, msg_length) = %u\n", (unsigned)offsetof(struct CCClntPkt, msg_length));
    printf("offsetof(struct CCClntPkt, client_string) = %u\n", (unsigned)offsetof(struct CCClntPkt, client_string));

    return 0;
}
```

In particular, it's quite possible that `long` is longer on your new host than your old one.  This is likely to be a good place to use the C99 exact-width types from `<stdint.h>` - if, on your original host, `short` is a 16 bit type and `long` is a 32 bit type, replace those with `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` respectively.

You can then use `ntohs()` and `ntohl()` to perform the endianness corrections.

Answer (score 1):

```
msg_ID = BCpacket_in[4] << 24;
msg_ID |= BCpacket_in[5] << 16;
msg_ID |= BCpacket_in[6] << 8;
msg_ID |= BCpacket_in[7];
```

This seems correct to me.

Try to use unsigned char for your buffer to protect yourself from signedness problem.

BTW, is msg_id in big endian, and are you sure of the offset: as you said "packing" didn't work on client side, so one can conclude that the structure is sent to the wire using the packing rules of the mainframe.

Comment: What's wrong with `ntohl`? It ought to be faster on x86-linux than the bitshift mechanism, as it'll use built-in assembler operations for the byte swap operation

Comment: ntohl() need a variable, it doesn't work with a pointer, so in order to use ntohl(), you have to create a pointer to a long which may break if the address is not correctly aligned or you have to copy the byte in a long variable than call ntohl(), which is doing 2x the byte copy.

Comment: @bdonlan A 32-bit logical shift is pretty hard to beat efficiency-wise. Apart from the array indexing, it should be translated to a single CPU instruction. I suspect you won't notice any difference in speed between the two methods.

Comment: @Lundin, you're doing three shifts and three ORs. The Linux implementation of `ntohl` on x86 does three logical rotations, exploiting the 16-bit halves of 32-bit registers. That's it. And if the right CPU flags are passed in, it just uses the built-in `BSWAP` assembler operation. So yes, it does beat 32-bit logical shifts, on x86 and x86-64.

Comment: @bdonlan Ok I see. Though a clever optimizer should perhaps be able to do the same. Still, in this context I doubt a few instructions more or less will matter.

Comment: I doubt a clever optimizer would be able to figure out `rol ax, ax; rol eax, eax; rol ax, ax` from your ORs and shifts there :)

Comment: And if the long is not naturally aligned, any gain you will get from ntohl over the bit shifting will go down the drain, as the cpu(assuming x86) spends time fixing up the alignment behind your back (lucky enough, some architectures will just crash your program in such a case)

Comment: @nos on other arch than x86, if long is not aligned, it can result on data corruption or program crash.

Comment: Thanks ydroneaud, changing the buffer to unsigned char fixed that issue.  Hard to accept an answer here, they were all very useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I usually do for packed structures sent/received to/from the network:

```
#define PACKED __attribute__((__packed__))
struct PACKED message { ... };
```

This is GCC-specific, see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.5/gcc/Type-Attributes.html#Type-Attributes). Then you have to figure out what size the `long` is here. It's different on 32- and 64-bit platforms. You might want to look into using [`stdint.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h) types instead. Also look info [`__builtin_bswap32()` and `__builtin_bswap64()` GCC intrinsics](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.5/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins).